# Typescript, pass arguments to Ejs page

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I didn't set anything like the code below at first, just res.render('view', {prams}); I kept getting an error saying that the set header does not work.

"Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Then, now that it is covered with the header below code, the related error has disappeared, but the ejs page is not receiving any parameters and <%=%> does not work. I'm not good at node js, so I'm actually using it as a clone. Could this possibly have something to do with cors? (I don't know what cors is well) Is there any way to send parameters here anyway?

```
            res.statusCode = 200;
            
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});
            res.header({'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});
            res.status(200).render("abcejs", {dataA, dataB});
```

Comment: what syntax are you using to print data on your ejs file?

Comment: @Aimsat Hi, I use like this "<%=dataName%>"

Comment: console log the data before rendering. it might be undefined.

Comment: @Aimsat yah I already actually did it and it comes out so well

Comment: @Aimsat If I don`t set header then this occurs "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: this error should occur with your current code. What is happening when you are using only this line --> res.status(200).render("abcejs", {dataA, dataB});

Comment: that still show that error I have to put this line "res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});" and currently this also does not work ejs.renderFile('views/abc.ejs', {data: data}, function (err, data) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(data);
                })

Comment: did you set view engine to ejs?

Comment: @Aimsat yes except passing arguments, everything is fine if I delete parameters, then it shows normal web page as expected

Comment: i can't understand the reason. does it show any error message when you pass the parameters?

Comment: @Aimsat Okay, there are two errors, if I don`t "write header" then it shows me "header error" and if I set "header" then no more shows "error header" but still shows error "data is not defined" but just right before I sent parameter through res.render ejs, if I do console.log(data), then it shows me clearly, and if I delete the <=%data=> then it does not occur error again too

Comment: @Aimsat I think ejs is not good, considering alternatives do you have any idea?

Comment: ejs is good. it will require some time to learn any syntax. just have some patience :) try the following changes and let me know if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining data properly. I am assuming your data is defined as follows:

```
var dataA = somedataA;
var dataB = somedataB;
```

And you are passing them like this:

```
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});
res.header({'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});
res.status(200).render("abcejs", {dataA, dataB});
```

You should display data in following manner:

```
<%= dataA %>
<%= dataB %>
```

You can't print <%= data %> as you defined dataA and dataB. if you want to display parameters with different names then you have to define them while rendering like this:

```
 res.status(200).render("abcejs", {
  data1: dataA, 
  data2: dataB
 });
```

then you can display with `<%= data1 %> <%= data2 %>`

Learn more about ejs syntax: [ejs.co](https://ejs.co/)

Comment: Hi Thanks, but now it is very weird.. I just realized that If I set header and console.log, the data is gone. but before set header, console.log appears well

Comment: Okay it does not work too,   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'}).status(200).render("abcejs", {
                    dataA: dataA,
                });

Comment: yah I did it, fk, I did really stupid things for 6hours.. At the very bottom, there was one more res.render statement by mistake. I couldn't see it it was  too at the bottom and underneath. I`m really sorry and thankful for all the your effort god bless you thanks